# Selecting multiple attribute values from a single element

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble using an XPath query in the Html Agility Pack to retrieve attribute values where the query matches multiple values on a single element.

I have the following test code:

```
string html = @"
<html>
    <body>
        <img height='5' src='http://bar1.com/foo.png' lowsrc='http://bar2.com/foo.png' />
        <img src='http://bar3.com/foo.png' />
    </body>
</html>";
string xPathQuery = "//img/@src | //img/@lowsrc";

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

IEnumerable<string> values = htmlDoc.CreateNavigator()
                                    .Select(xPathQuery)
                                    .OfType<HtmlNodeNavigator>()
                                    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

I expect the result to be:

```
http://bar1.com/foo.png
http://bar2.com/foo.png
http://bar3.com/foo.png
```

However, I get:

```
http://bar1.com/foo.png
http://bar3.com/foo.png
```

Note, the second attribute in the first img element is missing.

Is there a way to achieve this using a single XPath query? I know I could use XPath to find all the `img` elements and then read the attributes directly, but an XPath query returning all values would be more convenient.

Comment: `//img/@src | //img/@lowsrc` this is absolutely correct XPath and it should return exactly what you want. Mb something wrong with Html Agility Pack?

Comment: Curious as to why this question would be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Html Agility Pack doesn't support attribute selection http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/1720

This will do the trick:

```
string xPathQuery = "//img[@src or @lowsrc]";

var values = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPathQuery)
    .SelectMany(n => new[] {n.Attributes["src"], n.Attributes["lowsrc"]})
    .Where(n => n != null)
    .Select(a => a.Value);
```

Comment: That issue thread is 9 years old. The pack does support attribute selection as the results that my code gets demonstrates. There seems to be a bug, however, if the XPath expression matches multiple attributes on the same node

Comment: @AndrewCooper, prob